# .htaccess overwrites parent .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I've been struggling with this for a whole day and nothing helped so far.
I've got a PyroCMS installed in the root of the domain and a sub-domain blog in the same folder (public_html).

Now the problem is that when visiting http://dev.iber.co.uk/blog/ I'm seeing blog.iber.co.uk instead. Obviously that's because the blog folder exists and it's not just a url rewritten by htaccess.

The folder structure:

```
public_html
   blog
      .htaccess
      .index.php
      etc..
   .htaccess
   index.php
   etc..
```

However if I remove the htaccess from blog folder dev.iber.co.uk/blog/ gets rewritten to index.php as it should.

Here's the .htaccess for the dev.iber.co.uk(this sub-domain is actually pointing at root public_html folder):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system\/cms\/cache|system\/codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.iber\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Here's the .htaccess from the wordpress blog:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.iber\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

What am I doing wrong? I have no access to rewrite log cause it's a shared server. I will give 50 rep for anyone who helps me solve it.

Thanks

Comment: why is blog/.index.php dot-prefixed? parent folder htaccess is read first so any rewrite matches done there with [L] will be the last rewrite. you'd probably want a redirect between domains - if url is entered as a path /blog/, send to blog. subdomain with redirect not rewrite

Comment: What do you expect to see when you go to http://dev.iber.co.uk/blog/ ?

Comment: I expect to see a page with the blog which belongs to the dev.iber.co.uk - it has nothing to do with blog.iber.co.uk

Comment: It's a simple page which should be rewritten to index.php within dev.iber.co.uk

Comment: do you have control over DocumentRoot for virtual hosts  - 'shared server' so no i guess? And correct me if im wrong, dev../blog is not related to file objects within the dir, its only an alternative url pattern to direct view/model right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I don't have access to the configuration and dev/blog is just a url. I was advised to merge these somehow, but nothing I tried helped me so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the parent htaccess, would this solve your situation or is it a nescessity for you to have access to */blog/ path* from the *dev.domain* ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^dev.iber.co.uk$     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/blog/              [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$     blog.iber.co.uk/$1   [R=302.L]
... other rules
```